# How to jump to next text box

Tags: vb.net

I have n number of textbox

```
text1.text = ""
text2.text = ""
...
```

table1

```
id txt1 txt2 txt3  

01 0 0 1
02 1 1 0
.....
```

txt1, txt2 are bit datatype

I want to check from table1 if textbox bit is 0 then i dont want to focus the textbox, then move to next textbox if bit is 1 then i want to focus the textbox.  How to do it.

For example

```
table1

txt1 1
txt2 0
txt3 1

textbox1.focus then textbox3.focus.  
textbox2 should not focus
```

I which event i want to write a code leave_event or got focus event.  Any suggestion

Need VB.Net code help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [`Enter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx) event instead because [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx) notes that

> the GotFocus and LostFocus events are low-level focus events that are
>   tied to the WM_KILLFOCUS and WM_SETFOCUS Windows messages. Typically,
>   the GotFocus and LostFocus events are only used when updating UICues
>   or when writing custom controls. Instead **the Enter and Leave events
>   should be used for all controls** except the Form class, which uses the
>   Activated and Deactivate events.

You can use your logic there and call [`SelectNextControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol.aspx) if this `TextBox` should not get focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `TabIndex property` on `your controls`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445718(v=vs.60).aspx